# How can I define orthogonality in $GF(2)$?

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, coding-theory

Code Division Multiple Access (CDMA) makes (among others) use of Walsh-Hadamard matrices in which every row and column are orthogonal and each auto-correlation is fairly low. One example in ${\mathbb R}$ is:

$$
H^{(a)} = \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 1 \\
  1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Clearly $<h_1, h_2> = 1\cdot 1 - 1\cdot 1 = 0$. I would like to explore to which extend I can apply a CDMA code (based on Hadamard matrices) to a binary string defined in $GF(2)$ (and **not** $GF(2^m)$).

One matrix for a code-length of two would be:

$$
H^{(b)} = \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} .
$$

Addition in $GF(2)$ corresponds to bitwise XOR wheras multiplication corresponds to AND. Applying this I obtain $<h_1,h_2> = <[0,1], [1,0]> = ( 0\,\&\,1\, \oplus \,1\,\&\,0) = 0$, as expected.

However, also $<[0,0], [1,0]> = ( 0\,\&\,1\, \oplus \,0\,\&\,0) = 0$. But I don't think these vectors are orthogonal in $GF(2)$ (or are they?).
If I use these for CDMA coding, the station that uses the code $[0,0]$ would always output a zero-stream, independent of the data.

In fact, only $\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ would generate a non-zero inner product (according to my definition).

So I assume my definition of the inner product is wrong.

Comment: To get anything that resembles the physical properties of the signals you need to map elements of $GF(2)$ to real numbers. This is "always" done by the recipe
$$x\mapsto (-1)^x.$$ In other words the element $0\in GF(2)$ becomes the real number $+1$, and the element $1\in GF(2)$ becomes $-1$. The inner products of the resulting sequences of real numbers are what CDMA devices can work with.

Comment: On the $GF(2)$ side the inner product of the matching $\pm1$ sequences can be rewritten using the Hamming weight. If $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are two sequences of $n$ bits, i.e. elements of $GF(2)^n$, then the inner product of their $\pm1$ variants is
$$\langle (-1)^{\vec{a}},(-1)^{\vec{b}}\rangle = n-2w,$$ where $w$ is the Hamming distance of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$. That is, the Hamming weight of their (modulo two) sum $\vec{a}+\vec{b}$. Now we see that to get a small inner product (or a low correlation), we want $w$ to be close to $n/2$.

Comment: In coding theory we can and do use the "inner product" of $GF(2)^n$:
$$\langle(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n),(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)\rangle=x_1y_1+\cdots+x_ny_n\in GF(2).$$ This is used to define dual codes, parity check equations, syndromes and such. But it is useless for the purposes of CDMA.

Comment: From the finite field side, the structure related to the inner products of sequences are known as *character sums*. For example, the Walsh-Hadamard transform can be seen as such. The correlation properties of CDMA-sequences, $m$-sequences, Gold sequences etc should all be viewed as character sums over $GF(2^m)$ or $GF(2)^n$ as the case may be.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thank you, lots of useful info here! First, I'd like to emphasize I know how CDMA "classically" works. But I want to explicitely explore the option to define it over GF(2) only (i.e., data and chipping sequence are binary only). With the "inner product" definition you explained, the inner product of the vectors of the GF(2) vectors $[0,1]$ and $[1,0]$ would be -2 (or 1 when back in GF(2)). But I am sure these vectors are orthogonal, so their inner product should be 0 in GF(2) (or positive when expressed in $\pm 1$ variant) -- no?

Comment: It would be amazing if you could give a couple of examples with the set of vectors $[0,0]$, $[1,0]$, $[0,1]$, $[1,1]$. For reference, I am running the following MATLAB definition `dp = @(a,b) (((-1).^a) * ((-1).^b)'); dp([0,0], [0,0]); dp([0,0], [0,1]);` ... `dp([1,1], [1,1])` and would expect only $[1,0]$ and $[0,1]$ to be orthogonal.

Comment: If you want something CDMA-like strictly in the $GF(2)$ domain, look up *Optical CDMA*. CDMA in an optical fibre instead of a radio channel. The resulting autocorrelation (between cyclic shifts) and crosscorrelation may be more to your liking.

Comment: A basic problem in $GF(2)$ is that there is no concept of *smaller*. Vectors with real numbers can be "nearly orthogonal", when their inner product is small in comparison to their length. In CDMA it is essential that a few small inner products won't add up to a large inner product. This is utterly meaningless if the inner product takes values in $GF(2)$!! The only meaningful *length* of a vector in $GF(2)^n$ is $n$. Furthermore, if we call $0$ a small inner product and $1$ large, then this is too sensitive. A single misinterpreted bit will flip one to the other.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Please consider combining all your comments into an _answer_ so that this question does not remain "unanswered".